# Appium installed but command not found

Tags: npm, appium, npm-install, appium-android, appium-ios

I have installed appium using `npm -install appium -g` and it installed. But when I type Appium --version I get command not found.

[image: terminal output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ln -fs /Users/<your user name>/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js /usr/local/bin/appium
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/appium
```

Comment: You should explain what this command does and what was the issue